# Have Dijkstra compute widest path

Tags: dijkstra

I would like to modify the dijkstra algorithm to compute the widest path. I know I have to change the **sum to min** and **min to max** but I am having difficulty making the changes in the code.

Please take a look at the code below and suggest where and how to make the changes. Thanks.

```
public class DijkstraAlgorithm {

    private final List<Vertex> nodes;
    private final List<Edge> edges;
    private Set<Vertex> settledNodes;
    private Set<Vertex> unSettledNodes;
    private Map<Vertex, Vertex> predecessors;
    private Map<Vertex, Integer> distance;

    public DijkstraAlgorithm(Graph graph) {
        // create a copy of the array so that we can operate on this array
        this.nodes = new ArrayList<Vertex>(graph.getVertexes());
        this.edges = new ArrayList<Edge>(graph.getEdges());
    }

    public void execute(Vertex source) {
        settledNodes = new HashSet<Vertex>();
        unSettledNodes = new HashSet<Vertex>();
        distance = new HashMap<Vertex, Integer>();
        predecessors = new HashMap<Vertex, Vertex>();
        distance.put(source, 0);
        unSettledNodes.add(source);
        while (unSettledNodes.size() > 0) {
            Vertex node = getMinimum(unSettledNodes);
            settledNodes.add(node);
            unSettledNodes.remove(node);
            findMinimalDistances(node);
        }
    }

    private void findMinimalDistances(Vertex node) {
        List<Vertex> adjacentNodes = getNeighbors(node);
        for (Vertex target : adjacentNodes) {
            // looks at the connected nodes in the graph
            if (getShortestDistance(target) > getShortestDistance(node) + getDistance(node, target)) // looks at the source (node), then at the adjacent nodes and then the target one by one
            {
                distance.put(target, getShortestDistance(node) + getDistance(node, target));
                predecessors.put(target, node);
                unSettledNodes.add(target);
            }
        }
    }

    private int getDistance(Vertex node, Vertex target) {
        for (Edge edge : edges) {
            if (edge.getSource().equals(node) && edge.getDestination().equals(target)) {
                return edge.getWeight();
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Should not happen");
    }

    private List<Vertex> getNeighbors(Vertex node) {
        List<Vertex> neighbors = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Edge edge : edges) {
            if (edge.getSource().equals(node) && !isSettled(edge.getDestination())) {
                neighbors.add(edge.getDestination());
            }
        }
        return neighbors;
    }

    private Vertex getMinimum(Set<Vertex> vertexes) {
        Vertex minimum = null;
        for (Vertex vertex : vertexes) {
            if (minimum == null) {
                minimum = vertex;
            } else {
                if (getShortestDistance(vertex) < getShortestDistance(minimum)) {
                    minimum = vertex;
                }
            }
        }
        return minimum;
    }

    private boolean isSettled(Vertex vertex) {
        return settledNodes.contains(vertex);
    }

    private int getShortestDistance(Vertex destination) {
        Integer d = distance.get(destination);
        if (d == null) {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        } else {
            return d;
        }
    }

    /*
     * This method returns the path from the source to the selected target and
     * NULL if no path exists
     */
    public LinkedList<Vertex> getPath(Vertex target) {
        LinkedList<Vertex> path = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
        Vertex step = target;
        // check if a path exists
        if (predecessors.get(step) == null) {
            return null;
        }
        path.add(step);
        while (predecessors.get(step) != null) {
            step = predecessors.get(step);
            path.add(step);
        }
        // Put it into the correct order
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

}
```

As far as I can see, I think I have to make changes to `findMinimalDistances` and `getMinimum`. I understand how both Dijkstra and Widest path work on paper but in terms of code, I'm having some difficulty.

Comment: This really seems like a homework assignment. The key to understanding how code works is to step through it on paper, drawing the data structures and updating the values with each step. Sometimes you can use a debugger, but for something this complex, it's better to draw it out on paper or a whiteboard.

Comment: Also, try posting some of the changes you have tried, not just asking for answer without doing any work yourself.